# Powershell Copy-Item PS1 Script

Tags: powershell

```
Function CopyTwolocations ($from, $to)
{
Copy-Item -Path $from $to -Recurse -Force
$?
if($false) {Return}
}

CopyTwolocations -from "C:\Test1\Subtest1\*" -to "\\Testserver\Back-Ups\TEST\%date:~0,3%\"
CopyTwolocations -from "C:\TESTMYSQL\*" -to "\\Testserver\Back-Ups\TEST\%date:~0,3%\"
```

I am having trouble. I want to be able to make a sub folder for every day but all I have that works is %date:~0,3%\

but I know powershell does this but I am not quite sure how to copy it into the location of the day you copy it.

```
$a = Get-Date
$a.DayOfWeek
```

Comment: What errors do you get when you try our answers below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do things in PowerShell. Another alternative is:

```
CopyTwolocations -from "C:\TESTMYSQL\*" -to "\\Testserver\Back-Ups\TEST\$(get-date -f ddd)\"
```

And since PowerShell allows for positional parameters that could be simplified to:

```
CopyTwolocations C:\TESTMYSQL\* "\\Testserver\Back-Ups\TEST\$(get-date -f ddd)\"
```

Modify you function to create the destination directory if it doesn't exist:

```
Function CopyTwolocations ($from, $to)
{
    if (!(Test-Path $to)) {
        md $to
    }
    Copy-Item -Path $from $to -Recurse -Force
    $?
   if($false) {Return}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

most direct method: `-to "\\Testserver\Back-Ups\TEST\$(get-date -format 'dddd')"`

My preferred method:

```
$Destination = '\\Testserver\Back-Ups\TEST\{0:dddd}' -f (get-date);
... -to "$Destination"
```

Answer (score 0):

Could I append something like this to the end of these ?

```
CopyTwolocations -from "C:\Test1\Subtest1\*" -to "\\Testserver\Back-Ups\TEST\%date:~0,3%\" -name ("Docs-"+ (Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd)) -type directory
CopyTwolocations -from "C:\TESTMYSQL\*" -to "\\Testserver\Back-Ups\TEST\%date:~0,3%\" -name ("Docs-"+ (Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd)) -type directory
```